# get username after login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I want to get the username after login but it doesn't work.

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string strUser;

        protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            strUser = Membership.GetUser().UserName;

            Response.Redirect("Home");
        }
        protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            strUser = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
            Response.Redirect("Home");
        }
    }
```

This is my error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Membership.GetUser().UserName` is null, because the new principal object is not attached to the current HttpContext object yet.

So you need to explicitly retrieve that recently logged-in user using username from `Login` control.

**Update: Credit to jadarnel27**

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
  // Get the username from login control and retrieves the user info explicitly
  Membership user = Membership.GetUser(Login1.Username); 
  ...
}
```

Comment: You can use `Login1.UserName` to get the user name that was typed in to the Login control (rather than finding and casting the TextBox).  +1 from me though, this is plausible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check and make sure the user's login was successful.  It looks like you're just using standard ASP.NET membership, so this should work:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Authenticated)
    {
        strUser = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
        Response.Redirect("Home");
    }
    else
    {
        strUser = "Login Failed!";
    }
}
```

It's been a while since I worked with these controls, but you might need to determine the value of `e.Authenticated` yourself first and set it.  If so, you need to put this before the if-block I wrote above:

```
bool authenticated = Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);
e.Authenticated = authenticated;
```

I think vanilla ASP.NET membership handles that part for you; if you were using a custom authentication scheme, you would definitely need to do that step.